# Drools - multiple activation group

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I have written a Drool rule as shown below:

```
rule "first and second"
        activation-group "first"
        activation-group "second"
    when
        // conditions
    then
        // actions
end
```

However, when compiling, I get this error:

```
Duplicate attribute definition: activation-group in rule first and second
```

I want to know if it is possible to include multiple `activation-groups` in a rule. If this is possible, how can you do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to use multiple activation groups in a single rule. If you feel the need to do this then you should restructure your rules to be a little smarter with your conditions so you can get it to a state that would work with single activation groups (per rule).